# Set Pandas Column to NumPy Array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Let's say that I have a NumPy Array:

```
x = np.array([0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 0, 5, 2, 2, 1])
```

and a Pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'start': [2, 5, 1, 0, 0], 'stop': [6, 9, 4, 3, 2]})

#    start  stop
# 0      2     6
# 1      5     9
# 2      1     4
# 3      0     3
# 4      0     2
```

The `start` and `stop` columns correspond to the start and stop indices from the NumPy array `x`. So, I would like to add a third column to the DataFrame that represents the sequence (object) from `x`. I can accomplish this using `iterrows`:

```
df['sequence'] = [[] for _ in range(len(df))]
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    df.at[idx, 'sequence'] = x[row['start']:row['stop']]

#    start  stop      sequence
# 0      2     6  [1, 3, 4, 0]
# 1      5     9  [0, 5, 2, 2]
# 2      1     4     [1, 1, 3]
# 3      0     3     [0, 1, 1]
# 4      0     2        [0, 1]
```

However, for a DataFrame with millions of rows, `iterrows` becomes undesirable. I need a solution that is both fast and that doesn't require a ton of memory to be consumed.

Comment: If you need lists or arrays that vary in length (shape), you most likely will need to iterate.  The fast whole-array operations produce multidimensional arrays, not 'ragged' ones.  As long as each row of `sequence` is a slice/view of `x` the memory consumption won't be large.  But keep in mind that it is difficult to 'save' such a dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about we do not do iterrows with `zip` and for loop

```
[x[s:t]for s , t in zip(df.start,df.stop)]
[array([1, 3, 4, 0]), array([0, 5, 2, 2]), array([1, 1, 3]), array([0, 1, 1]), array([0, 1])]
#df['sequence'] = [x[s:t]for s , t in zip(df.start,df.stop)]
```

Comment: This turned out to be really fast!

Comment: @slaw glad I can help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
>>> x = np.array([0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 0, 5, 2, 2, 1])
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'start': [2, 5, 1, 0, 0], 'stop': [6, 9, 4, 3, 2]})
>>> df['sequence'] = [x[df['start'][idx]:df['stop'][idx]] for idx in range(len(df))]
>>> df

#   start  stop      sequence
# 0      2     6  [1, 3, 4, 0]
# 1      5     9  [0, 5, 2, 2]
# 2      1     4     [1, 1, 3]
# 3      0     3     [0, 1, 1]
# 4      0     2        [0, 1]
```